# DDMS is not showing my apps data or any other data through android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, ddms

I have connected my device through USB and the app and the device is showing in the DDMS device section but the app's data or caches are not showing.

[image: DDMS Screenshots]

[image: DDMS not showing any data]

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you are checking this in android device not in emulator right ? and what api level ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela I am using android device and the api level is 25

Comment: @AmitVaghela so it won't show for devices for api   24+ ?

Comment: you need to create emulator lower api than 23 or 23. you can tell me if that doest work@Sushrita

Comment: @AmitVaghela yes it's working for emulator 23 or lower .i have created one with api 22 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any device (not Emulator) then you can't get access to 'data' directory. This directory is protected. You only access that directory if your device is **Rooted**.

Comment: i also can't access the directory in emulator and other devices